# Java stream multiply and return sum of multiplication

Tags: java, java-stream, bigdecimal

Currently I am using a for loop to perform a simple multiplication and sum the obtained values:

```
BigDecimal serviceOrderTotal = new BigDecimal(0.00);
for (int i = 0; i < orderPresenter.getServiceList().size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("orderPresenter.getServiceList().get(i).getServiceValue()");
    System.out.println(orderPresenter.getServiceList().get(i).getServiceValue());
    System.out.println("orderPresenter.getServiceList().get(i).getServiceQuantity()");
    System.out.println(orderPresenter.getServiceList().get(i).getServiceQuantity());
    serviceOrderTotalold = serviceOrderTotal.add(orderPresenter.getServiceList().get(i).getServiceValue().multiply(orderPresenter.getServiceList().get(i).getServiceQuantity()));
}
```

I need to do the same using streams. For each of the orderPresenters, I need to multiply value for the quantity and return the sum of those values.

If I do it using a `forEach` in the `stream`, I cannot return the value cause the variable must be `final` or atomic to be used inside the forEach. I ended up with this to no avail:

```
BigDecimal serviceOrderTotal = new BigDecimal(0.00);
serviceOrderTotal = orderPresenter.getServiceList().stream()
               .forEach(servicePresenter -> {
                    System.out.println("orderPresenter.getServiceValue()");
                    System.out.println(orderPresenter.getServiceValue());
                    System.out.println("orderPresenter.getServiceQuantity()");
                    System.out.println(orderPresenter.getServiceQuantity());
                    serviceOrderTotalold = serviceOrderTotalold.add(orderPresenter.getServiceValue().multiply(orderPresenter.getServiceQuantity()));
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the list, do this. Not certain what your List looks like.

```java
BigDecimal sum = list.stream()
                     .map(sv -> sv.getServiceValue().multiply(sv.getServiceQuantity()))
                     .reduce(new BigDecimal(0.0), (a, b) -> a.add(b));
```

Comment: `new BigDecimal(0.0)` equals `BigDecimal.ZERO`. `(a,b) -> a.add(b)` is equivalent of `BigDecimal::add`.

Your code is not readable.

Comment: Of course my code is readable.  You just proved it.  But they do exactly the same thing.  Not certain why a duplicate answer was  posted after mine though.

Comment: Yes, they do the same thing, but when a random person looks at the other answer, they immediately get what is the point. On the other hand, your code is hard to understand even when you know what it does.

Comment: Thank you both guys. Both are the same answer, so I went with the first one.

Comment: @xenteros: I find his code is about as readable as it would be with your suggested changes. You might have a point about `BigDecimal::add`, but certainly `new BigDecimal(0.0)` is as readable as `BigDecimal.ZERO`, perhaps even more so to non-English speakers.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk you should never initialize BigDecimal with a float or double but with a String

Comment: @xentero  Unless it's zero which has no finite decimal expansion problems.  Interesting how the API still has it (as of Java 13) and the powers that be have yet seen fit to deprecate it.

Comment: @xenteros: 0.0 is exactly representable and presents no problem in initializing BigDecimal.

Answer (score 6):

You can modify your implementation to use a foreach such as:

```
BigDecimal serviceOrderTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (Service service : orderPresenter.getServiceList()) {
    serviceOrderTotal = serviceOrderTotal.add(service.getServiceValue().multiply(service.getServiceQuantity()));
}
```

This can also be transformed using the `map` and `reduce` operations of java-stream further as:

```
BigDecimal serviceOrderTotal = orderPresenter.getServiceList().stream()
        .map(service -> service.getServiceValue().multiply(service.getServiceQuantity()))
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```